# Auto restart in case of failure with Kiln and 18.04

Tags: node, baking

I just installed Kiln on my intel nuc with Ubuntu 18.04. It seems to work flawless. From my understanding, Ubuntu should be able to update without restarting. I also got a UPS, so most of the risks should be covered. However, I’d like to know if there’s a script which makes Kiln auto restart in case it shuts down without my knowledge. I read something about a script from Etom Knudson, but I’m not sure if it works on Ubuntu 18.04 and how to install.